# Javascript load function only works half of the time (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, svg, load

When I use the following code

```
<object id="svg" data="assets/mySVG.svg" type="image/svg+xml">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   document.getElementById('svg').addEventListener("load", function() {
      console.log('test');
   });
});
</script>
```

It will only load half of the time. Sometimes when I refresh it loads, sometimes it doesn't. Once the SVG document is cached it allways loads. This only happens in firefox, in chrome it loads 100% of the time.

Comment: when it doesn't load, do you get an error in the developer tools console?

Comment: Maybe make sure the whole page has loaded as well before running the script.

Comment: No errors, also I do check if the whole page is loaded before running the script (just made a small snippet as example), I will edit to avoid confussion.

Comment: @inControl I assume that 50% of the time the object loads before the page itself has completely loaded so by the time you've had document.ready the load event for the svg has already fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might could be a cache problem, also keep in mind that the event `Load` occurs after the DOM is ready, and probably the SVG Object loads before because is on the cache, how ever you can try loading it without using jQuery, as i had read before the jQuery `ready` event takes longer to start because, first the jQuery Library needs to load and probably the SVG is already loaded when the `ready` event occurs, add a script like this, before the `</body>`:

```
<script>
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var init();
    init = function(){
        document.getElementById('svg').addEventListener("load", function() {
            console.log('test');
        });
    }
    init();
})();
</script>
```

Comment: The occured indeed because the svg was loaded before the document was ready when cached.